# Different results when running PHPUnit from commandline than from netbeans

Tags: netbeans, laravel-4, phpunit, netbeans-8

I have single test

```
    $response=$this->call('GET', '/');
    $this->assertResponseOk();
```

that fails with  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException when I run

```
phpunit
```

from commandline in project dir and I have phpunit.xml (from laravel) in project dir

BUT when I run tests from Netbeans - it passes.

I copied Netbeans output command to commandline

```
phpunit "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\platform\workbench\neyl\customers\tests;C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\platform\app\tests"
```

and it also works!

So, test works when being called from NetbeansSuite.php but not from regular commandline.
Even

```
phpunit MyTest.php
```

fails

**How can this be? What factor is diiferent when using PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite than regular cli?**

Comment: Maybe this issue occurs because of different versions of phpunit.

Comment: As mentioned, I am replicating the Netbeans testsuite via cli calling the phpunit.bat found in my path so both tests are DEFINITELY using same version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The discrepancy was caused by order tests were called.
phpunit from cli uses testsuites from phpunit.xml but the netbeans tests don't use the phpunit.xml for testsuites so they were called in order netbeans was calling them

Now I have to work out what the order of testclasses is causing!